# Laravel 8: installation authentication with inertia is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication, inertiajs, laravel-breeze

I am starting to build a web application using Laravel 8. I am now trying to install the authentication in my application. I am trying to use Breeze and inertia. But it is not working as expected. This is how I installed it.

After I installed the Laravel, I run the following commands

- php artisan breeze:install --inertia
- npm install && npm run dev
- php artisan migrate

When I access my application on the browser it was throwing error saying "Inertia\Middleware" not found. So I run the following commands.

- composer require inertiajs/inertia-laravel
- npm install @inertiajs/inertia @inertiajs/inertia-vue3
- npm install && npm run dev
- php artisan migrate

When I access my application home page, I am only seeing this.

[image]

What's wrong with my installation and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the issue using these comands:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
chmod +x composer.phar
mv composer.phar /usr/local/bin/composer
laravel new myapp --jet --stack=inertia --teams
```

1. configure your .env
2. php artisan migrate
3. php artisan serve